# Storing numbers temporarily in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

What is the best way to go about storing numbers in memory within MATLAB but then writing only a specific subset of them to a matrix/array during a for-loop? I am also struggling to setup an appropriate for-loop for my problem:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPAAn.png]

I have a line of a specific length (x=100), and a barrier at specific position (pos=50). I want to carry out multiple rounds of sampling (in this case, 1000) and within each, generate a specific amount of random numbers (p). In the image shown, 4 numbers are generated, I want MATLAB to take the smallest number when p > pos and the largest number when p < pos then subtract them to give me the distance between the small possible fragment made that still includes the barrier. So in this example it would provide the distance between b and c.

Is this possible to do in MATLAB? I got as far as:

```
x = 100;
sample = 1000; %number of rounds of sampling to do
pos = 50; %position of barrier 
nn = 1:12; %the number of random numbers to generate for each round of sampling i.e. 1000 rounds generating 1 number, 1000 rounds generating 2 numbers and so on
len1 = 0;
len2= x ;
for i = 1:sample
    p(i) = int16(rand()*x)
    if (p(i)<pos) && (p(i)>len1) 
        len(i) = p(i)
    end
end
```

I know that i'd need a second if statement along the lines of

```
if (p(i)>pos) && (p(i)<len2)
```

My idea was to temporarily replace the values of len1 and len2 with the smallest and largest numbers generated during each round of sampling before reinitiating the loop with default len1 and len2 values. There may be a better way though.

Any help would be very much appreciated,

Comment: What happens if all of your generated random numbers lie on one side of the barrier?

Comment: Sorry - I forgot to mention this eventuality. In this case, the original value of either len1 or len2 would still remain and would be used in the subtraction. So if 'b' was the only number generated, the output would be 100-b.

Comment: What does the variable `nn` do? It looks like you don't use it. Also, what is the variable `sam`? Is that the same as `sample`?

Comment: Great, thanks for the edit. So do I have this clear - in this example you are generating 1000 points, and you want to choose the smallest point to the right of the barrier and the largest point to the left of the barrier, and record their difference?

Comment: Yes - sam = sample, i've updated the code. I have not yet used 'nn' as i'm not sure how to do so. 'nn' contains the number of random numbers i'd like to generate in each batch of sampling. For example if nn=1:2 and sample = 1000, i'd like MATLAB to do 1000 rounds where it only generates 1 number, store these results and then repeat this but generating 2 numbers.

Comment: Including what I just said above - yes that is correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you should do something like this

```
x = 100;       % length of the grid
pos = 50;      % position of the barrier
len1 = 0;      % left edge of the grid
len2 = x;      % right edge of the grid

sample = 1000; % number of samples to make
nn     = 1:12  % number of points to generate (will loop over these)

len = zeros(sample, length(nn)); % array to record the results

for n = 1:length(nn)                     % For each number of pts to generate
    numpts = nn(n);
    for i = 1:sample                     % For each round of sampling,
        p = round(rand(numpts,1) * x);   % generate 'numpts' random points.
        if any(p>pos)                    % If any are to the right of the barrier,
            pright = min(p(p>pos));      % pick the smallest.
        else
            pright = len2;
        end
        if any(p<pos)                    % If any are to the left of the barrier,
            pleft = max(p(p<pos));       % pick the largest.
        else
            pleft = len1;
        end
        len(i,n) = pright - pleft;       % Record the length of the interval.
    end
end
```

Comment: Great! This is perfect thank you. This has taught me a lot, especially about nested for-loops.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't address all the points in your question (best way to store numbers temporarily), but shows a vectorized approach of how you can get the two numbers closest (on each side) of a given number if you have a list of random numbers. As far as I can tell, that's part of what you're asking for.

```
n = 1000;         %// Number of random numbers
max_val = 100;    %// Max value
min_val = 0;      %// Min value
p = 50;           %// Border

x = rand(n,1)*(max_val-min_val)+min_val;  %// Vector of random numbers
s = sort([min_val; x; max_val]-p);        %// Sort vector, with border "shifted" to 0
ind = find(diff(sign(s)));        %// Find index of closest number smaller than p
res =  diff(s(ind:ind+1))    %// Difference between closest numbers on each side of p
```

Comment: This is really interesting. Thank you for adding it. I wasn't aware at all that you could do it this way.